# CertPathValidatorException when try to fetch photos from Instagram

Tags: android, ssl, instagram

I am developing a app in which I have to download user photos from instgram. I am using below url

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + userID+ "/media/recent/?access_token=" + access_token+ "&count=" + items + "&min_id=" + minId

This url working fine with PC browser but when I try it in my android app it does not give anything in  response but showing this.

06-06 10:32:34.834: I/X509Util(18041): Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

I am not able to understand what this problem is or how it can resolved. Please help me.

Comment: I don't know why but when I try this url in my mobile browser its working perfect. But now I have to work more.First of all get content on web browser and then get this content from browser and create list of photos.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. Actually I am using a common method which is used to get response from url. But in this method i am using post method. And "Instagram" doesn't gives anything in response and sometimes gives above error. Now After some R&D I changed "Post" to "Get"(means now I am using HttpGet). Now I am getting content actually a json string.